# UPDATE WHERE in MERGE

Tags: java, sql, derby, javadb

I'm trying to run the below query but I keep getting back:

```
Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 5, column 38.

MERGE INTO FOO
USING BAR
ON FOO."NAME" = BAR."NAME"
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET FOO."NAME" = 'qwerty' WHERE FOO."AGE" > 30
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (guid) values('qwerty')
```

If I remove `WHERE FOO."AGE" > 30` then it seems to be fine though. Is it not possible to specify a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` of a `MERGE`?

I'm using the latest apache derby embedded database version, `10.12.1.1`

Comment: yep, seems like  [mergeUpdate](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqljmerge.html#rrefsqljmerge__mergeupdate) simply does not allow WHERE clause. But Phritzy's answer below should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
MERGE INTO FOO
USING BAR
ON FOO."NAME" = BAR."NAME"
AND FOO."AGE" > 30
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET FOO."NAME" = 'qwerty'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (guid) values('qwerty')
```